# Persistent nav footer for the iphone with a HTML5 web app

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to have a persistent nav footer for the iphone with a HTML5 web app that is not a buggy implementation like jQuery mobile?

Even when you open up the jQuery mobile documentation ( http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html ) in an iPhone it doesn't stay put! It has like a "bouncing" effect where it jumps for a split second on page transitions

Comment: No, it's not possible, because iOS Safari doesn't support the CSS "position:fixed" property, and doesn't allow Javascript to update the page while a user is scrolling. Word on the street is that "position:fixed" is coming in iOS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked out Sencha Touch and their "bottom tabs" are looking real good - there must be a way using CSS and JS to achieve this effect. Inspecting their kitchen sink in the browser, it looks like they set a bottom tabs container to position:absolute. And then they set the appropriate css top property for the window load and window resize event. Seems pretty straightforward really why is jQUery mobile struggling with this feature?

Answer (score 2):

Open the Gmail web app (made in html) on iOS. (at https://mail.google.com/mail/mu)
the top bar stays on top without any flicker, so it can be done in some ways ...
But opening the same page on Chrome, the top bar scrolls, so this should be achieved with some iOS-specific trick.

I'll try to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 5, **a version** of this is waaay easy:

```
.header{
position: fixed;
top:0px;
z-index:1000;
...
}
```

NOTE: This will keep the header at the top of the screen when scrolling down forever, but when scrolling up the header will get pulled down and reveal the url bar when you reach the top. So, it's not exactly like the gmail or twitter apps, but it's a great start with very little coding needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on more persistently hidden url than my last answer allows (and a footer without less bounce), check out https://github.com/joelambert/ScrollFix/issues/2

Requires a handful of empty nested divs, but no external js, just fancy css!

Answer (score 0):

I think in iOS5 this should not be an issue because of static CSS positioning finally enabled. I know in iOS4 it in involves much JS trickery...